# Why i can't get session data through nuxtServerInit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a problem when i try getting sessions. Below are the main files. At least I need to find out if everything is configured correctly here: server, config?

**store/index.js**

```
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
  console.log(req);
}
```

this log shows me "undefined"

**api/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport');
const twitchStrategy = require("@d-fischer/passport-twitch").Strategy;

const app = express();

app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: "bla-bla-bla", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new twitchStrategy({
  clientID: 'bla-bla-bla',
  clientSecret: 'bla-bla-bla',
  callbackURL: "bla-bla-bla",
  scope: "user_read"
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  return done(null, profile);
}
));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

const user = require('./routes/user');
app.use(user);

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()
})

module.exports = app;

if (require.main === module) {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API server listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

I think it's not worth showing the contents of the **routes/user** file, everything is clear there.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
serverMiddleware: {
  '/api': '~/api'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

nuxt.config.js

target: 'static' => 'server'